# How to show list of file URLs stored in MEDIA folder using django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, rest

I am trying to create a django API where I can upload images against a unique username (without any authentication), and then the API can be fed the username to list all the IMAGES uploaded for that username. I am using the `\media\` folder to store the images.

**imgapi/models.py**

```
class File(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(blank=False, null=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='user')
```

**imgapi/serializers.py**

```
class FileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = File
        fields = ['file','name']
```

**imgapi/views.py**

```
class FileUploadView(APIView):
    parser_class = (FileUploadParser, MultiPartParser,)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

      file_serializer = FileSerializer(data=request.data)

      if file_serializer.is_valid():
          file_serializer.save()
          return Response(file_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
      else:
          return Response(file_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

So far with this, I can upload an image along with a username.
And it gives me a response in this format.

```
{
    "file": "/media/photo_2020-06-06_02-55-54.png",
    "name": "testUser"
}
```

**imgapi/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('upload/', include('imgapi.urls')),
    path('api/', include('imgapi.urls')),
]


if settings.DEBUG:
  urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

How can I retrieve a list of URLs for the username `testUser` by using, for example the given link
`https:\\localhost:8000\api\list\username=testUser`

**THANK YOU FOR WHOEVER DOWNVOTED MY QUESTION**

I have found a working solution, and I am going to update my answer.
I got the upload & filtering, both to work with a few edits in the views.py and urls.py

Updated ***views.py***

```
class GetImageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    
    queryset = Image.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ImageSerializer
    
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['uploaded_by']
```

Updated ***urls.py***

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'item', GetImageViewSet, basename='item')

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```